# Copy files within multiple directories to one directory

Tags: linux

We have an Ubuntu Server that is only accessed via terminal, and users transfer files to directories within 1 parent directory (i.e. /storage/DiskA/userA/doc1.doc /storage/DiskA/userB/doc1.doc). I need to copy all the specific files within the user folders to another dir, and I'm trying to specifically target the .doc extension.

I've tried running the following:

> cp -R /storage/diskA/*.doc /storage/diskB/monthly_report/

However, it keeps telling me there is no such file/dir.

I want to be able to just pull the .doc files from all the user dirs and transfer to that dir, /storage/monthly_report/.

I know this is an easy task, but apparently, I'm just daft enough to not be able to figure this out. Any assistance would be wonderful.

EDIT: I updated the original to show that I have 2 Disks. Moving from Disk A to Disk B.

Comment: Are you sure about what you want to do? Because, if you try to copy all `*.doc` files from any subdirectory from `/storage` to `/storage/monthly_report`, what will you do with the ones, already present in `/storage_monthly_report` (which is a subdirectory from `/storage` too)? Can't you choose another directory to copy your files to?

Comment: Well, we have 2 disks mounted. I should update the original to reflect that.

I have disk A mounted as /storage/diskA/userA and disk B mounted as /storage/diskB/monthly_report. I'm basically trying to migrate files from the subdirectories of A to B.

Comment: You might want to use `find dir -name "*.doc" -exec cp -n "{}" /dest_dir/ \;` Note that while the `-n` option would prevent overwriting, you cannot be sure that each and every file was copied

Answer (score 2):

I would go for `find -exec` for such a task, something like:

```
find /storage/DiskA -name "*.doc" -exec cp {} /storage/DiskB/monthly_report/ \;
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Nice one. If he has multiple directories that he wants to exclude he may need to loop through the path for each one

Comment: That worked! However, it looks like there are a few files that have a different name/extension. How would I go about targeting those specific files? i.e., filename is 'COMPANYuserA.txt' 'COMPANYuserB.txt' where the userA/B/C field will be specific to that user.  

Is there a way to wildcard while retaining the COMPANY and extension? I assume "COMPANY*.txt" would work, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 rsync -zarv --include="*/" --include="*.doc" --exclude="*"  /storage/diskA/*.doc /storage/diskB/monthly_report/
```